# How to use ng-if and ng-options together in angular 1

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I used below syntax to display username. I want to display username when `(user.company==userData.company)` in the below list. Please help me to achieve this.

```
<select ng-options="user.FirstName+' 'user.LastName for user in companyUsers | orderBy:'FirstName' track by user.Id" ng-if="user.company==userData.company" ng-model="selectedUser" ng-change="loadListNew()">
</select>
```

Comment: Please add an example of the data you're working with, it greatly helps people who try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ng-if="user.company==userData.company"` does not work because that would be applied to the select element.

**Filters Options**

Instead, you can use a filter directly inside your `ng-options` like in this [example.](http://jsfiddle.net/usahxbr4/)

**Filter Document**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Not able to get user.company as company comes as an array. {companyName:{company:'xxx'}, ...} . Please help.

Comment: You can replace `filter:{shade:'dark'}` by a call to a function with an argument like :
`filter:isDarkShade(color)` and then do whatever you want in that function
That function will return a Boolean.

Comment: {

"LocationId":1,
"PhoneNumber":null,

"Company":{
 
  "CompanyName":"xxx",
  "Color":{
   "ColorName":"#306448",
   "Id":3,   
   }
} How to apply filter now.

Comment: Can i add filter like this filter:isDarkShade(optionUserId.Company.CompanyName)

Comment: Well. I don't know where your `optionUserId` comes from.
You should pass as an argument your `user` from `companyUsers`. Then you just compare the stuff between user and your condition model.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your code: `user.FirstName + ' ' + user.LastName`, you forgot the second `+`.

Updated code:

```
<select ng-options="user.FirstName + ' ' + user.LastName for user in companyUsers | orderBy:'FirstName' track by user.Id" 
    ng-if="user.company==userData.company"
    ng-model="selectedUser"
    ng-change="loadListNew()">
</select>
```

---

But the problem is that `ng-if` does not work with `ng-options`, because `ng-options` does not create a new scope.

What you should do is create a filter, which removes the data from the input, so `ng-options` will skip it. You can apply it both before or after your `orderBy`-filter.

Comment: Not able to get user.company as company comes as an array. {companyName:{company:'xxx'}, ...}

Answer (score 0):

```
    You may move your logic to controller rather than in html. You may filter data $scope.companyUsers before bind it to select options. 

    $scope.companyUsers =  // where you assign the value to companyUsers of scope variable. below this code do something like
    $scope.companyUsers = $scope.companyUsers.map( function(companyUserObj){
     if(companyUserObj.company==$scope.userData.company)
    {
       return companyUserObj;
    }

    })
now bind this $scope.companyUsers to select options as below.
<select ng-options="user.FirstName+' '+user.LastName for user in companyUsers | orderBy:'FirstName' track by user.Id" ng-model="selectedUser" ng-change="loadListNew()">
</select>
```